# Can someone tell me why soapUI return an error when I try to loading a WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

I'm traying to loading a WSDL in soapUI but I receive an error. The log is:

```
Mon May 07 16:44:11 WEST 2018:ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaException
   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.buildSchemaTypes(SchemaUtils.java:266)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.loadSchemaTypes(SchemaUtils.java:177)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.loadSchemaTypes(XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.java:72)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlInterfaceDefinition.load(WsdlInterfaceDefinition.java:56)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:62)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:34)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.cacheDefinition(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:245)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.access$400(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:47)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:218)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

And the WSDL is:

```
https://pastebin.com/wUkDjJMp
```

Comment: I tried to edit your question with details from the SOAP-UI error pane/tab but SO wouldn't let me.  You're basically getting this error `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl cannot be cast to     
    org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xsdschema.Group` - not that it helps, but gets you a little closer to a possible answer

Comment: And it looks like googles not playing nice - hopefully someone here can help you better than myself as I'm clueless